# Set all labels, textfields and buttons (.....layer.cornerRadius = 10)

Tags: objective-c

how I can set ALL labels, textfields and buttons on my ViewController to ...layer.cornerRadius = 10? e.g. with a for-statement? or must all be set individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Subclass the classes and add a `UIAppearance` corner radius property. This will give you reusable classes which you can use in different view controllers with different corner radius values. You'll have to create 3 new classes and remember to set all of them in `Interface Builder` when adding new items.

2) Assuming everything is contained in the same view you can iterate through all of the subviews and check the class. If you end up using nested views you will need to check those subviews as well. Not the cleanest but if it's a simple view it's a good option.

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.f;
    }
}
```

3) You can create an `IBOutletCollection` and loop through it in the same way without having to check the class. This becomes annoying as you add/remove items over time.

Comment: perfect!! thanks for this excellent code... i've only added layer.masksToBounds = YES; thats it

Answer (score 0):

You can put them all in an `IBOutletCollection`, which is an array generated through Interface Builder. Similar to how you create an outlet, select Outlet Collection in the popup that comes up. Then drag all of the other UI items you want to iterate over in there. Note, though, that all of the items in a collections must be the same type. So if you have labels and buttons, you'll need a separate collection for each.

Alternatively, you can create a separate subclass of each type with their corner radius set (since you're apparently using that style of control so often) and use those classes in Interface Builder.